# How can I namespace Rails Routes to separate them from Angular Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a single page applications using Angular with the SQL handled by Rails.  Most of the routes are handled by Angular's UI-router.  However, I have admin routes which I want to be handled by Rails and not be a single page application.  What is the best way to have Rails handle the namespaced admin routes?  Currently when I navigate to /admin/users, it will redirect me to root.

config.routes.rb

```
      namespace 'admin' do
        resources :users
        ...
      end

      resources :users
      resources :videos

      root 'application#index'
      get '*path' => 'application#index'
```

angular_app.js

```
angular_app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'videos/index.html',
          controller: 'VideosController'
      })
      .state('home.video', {

      ......
      // default fall back route
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      // enable HTML5 Mode for SEO
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

      }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
      namespace 'admin' do
        resources :users
        ...
      end

      resources :users
      resources :videos

      get '/', :controller=> 'application',:action=>'index'
```

This way, You can now access admin routes using admin url helper.
Angular would come into picture when '/' is encountered.

If you need to access admin from Angular Page. You can do a Native Javascript Window.href and specify the admin url.